# Unable to get all the links within a page

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape this page:
https://www.jny.com/collections/bottoms

It has a total of 55 products listed with only 24 listed once the page is loaded. However, the div contains list of all the 55 products. I am trying to scrape that using scrappy like this :

```
def parse(self, response):
        print("in herre")
        self.product_url =  response.xpath('//div[@class = "collection-grid js-filter-grid"]//a/@href').getall()

        print(len(self.product_url))
        print(self.product_url)
```

It only gives me a list of length 25. How do I get the rest?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest scraping it through the API directly - the other option would be rendering Javascript using something like Splash/Selenium, which is really not ideal.

If you open up the Network panel in the Developer Tools on Chrome/Firefox, filter down to only the XHR Requests and reload the page, you should be able to see all of the requests being sent out. Some of those requests can help us figure out how the data is being loaded into the HTML. Here's a screenshot of what's going on there behind the scenes.

[image: Product API Requests]

Clicking on those requests can give us more details on how the requests are being made and the request structure. At the end of the day, for your use case, you would probably want to send out a request to `https://www.jny.com/collections/bottoms/products.json?limit=250&page=1` and parse the `body_html` attribute for each Product in the response (perhaps using `scrapy.selector.Selector`) and use that however you want. Good luck!

Comment: Only the Product descriptions are listed. It doesn't contain link to products